# What is the inverse of an FTDI FT232R?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, uart, usb-host

I have an existing device that takes the UART data from the internal CPU and uses an FT232R to present that UART as a USB device. It was designed to be easy to connect to a PC since most have FTDI virtual COM drivers built in now, or at least be easy to install.

For an expansion idea, I'd like to be able to connect a small dongle to that USB device port and read that serial stream back out (for example, to attach a battery-operated Bluetooth radio).

It seems crazy to have a whole dedicated processor to connect to that FTDI device just to get the serial data back out.  The possibilities I have located so far are the FTDI Viniculum (which looks to be completely unsupported and obsolete) and the MAX3421E.  The CH559 looks cheap and interesting but it also looks like something that could just disappear into thin air at any given moment.  It would probably also give our purchasing team a stroke just trying to locate it.

Previous questions on this topic are older than parts like the CH559 and vague about the MAX3421. Is there anything else out there that provides USB Host and does the de-USBization of the FT232R?

Comment: Part "shopping" questions are off topic.  Any solution to this will be a USB-host-capable MCU, either a general purpose one where you can customize the firmware and also implement the rest of your needs, or a special purpose one like the Viniculum with (effectively) ROM firmware which only does what the manufacturer wrote, and likely requiring yet another MCU of your own to implement the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Why not tap off at the RS232 level (ahead of the FT232) and connect THAT to the Bluetooth system?

Comment: The target device is closed and shipping, I can't go back and add a UART or RS-232 level port.

Comment: look at Raspberry Pi Zero or Pi Zero W ... it would allow you to connect your device and a second FT232R ... this would give you the power of Linux in a small package .. if you chose the Pi Zero W, then you would have network connectivity to use, instead of the second serial port

Comment: Then the question is, does it seem crazier to recall and drill holes to add ports, or to simply add an external CPU handling USB?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems crazy to have a whole dedicated processor to connect to that FTDI device just to get the serial data back out.

Unfortunately, that's the only way to do it. The Vinculum is just a microcontroller that has a USB host interface. There's no alternative to doing all the enumeration and polling process required to read USB.